# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First TPC problem

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, mapping, entity-framework-4.1

For the sake of simplicity let me simplify the system I am working on. In domain, class A derives from class B and B derives from C.

```
A : B
{
  a1, a2 //class members
}

B : C
{
  b1
}

C
{
  c1
}
```

configuration for A is like this:

```
class CConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<A>
{
  public DocumentConfiguration()
  {
     Map(x => x.MapInheritedProperties()).ToTable("DOCUMENT");
  }
}
```

Now, running code gives this error:

The property 'b1' is not a declared property on type 'A'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.

Why I'm getting this error?

At http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/adodotnetentityframework/thread/f89d1df5-3b1f-413d-a077-d354abf4cca6 it says "...you can't use intermediates". Is it true? If it is, then it is too bad that EF forces my domain to be in a specific design. For me it is as bad as putting data related attributes on top the domain classes. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are not showing all code. This should work. Linked question is about different type of inheritance with different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as well.  It's not an ideal answer but this is what worked for me...

The type of my property that was causing the error was a decimal.  I converted this to int throughout the project, built the solution and then converted it back to decimal and the error went away.

Not sure why this corrected the problem, but it worked for me.